# AES-128 encrypted HLS is not validated by media stream validator tool

Tags: ajax, http-live-streaming

I am using the MediaStreamValidator tool to check my HLS stream, which is encrypted with "AES-128" key. I kept my HLS stream segments and manifest file into apache server. I am using below command to validate my stream using media streamvalidator tool.

mediastreamvalidator "Apache URL path for manifest file" -O "name".json

But i am getting following error continuously and then report is generated.

"Unable to parse segment due to encryption format, only verifying download and bitrates"

Someone please confirm, whether media stream validator tool supports to validate the "AES-128" encrypted HLS stream or not?

Please refer the system configuration below.

MAC OS X Version : 10.9.5
MediaStreamValidator version:   1.1(151117)
Report generator version:   1.1(151117)

Thanks & Regards,
Ravikiran M

Comment: Why is this tagged [html]?

Comment: Hi BoltClock, This is my 1st question. So i don't know, which tag shall i need to use. Could you please guide me, which tag i need use

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `mediastreamvalidator` included with [Apple's HTTP Live Streaming tools](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) does not support encrypted variant playlists. The documentation around this is sparse and I was only able to find one reference to this deficiency in Apple's documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2454/_index.html:

> "The mediastreamvalidator only supports regular HLS m3u8 playlists so
>   you will need to run it against the unencrypted variant of your
>   content instead of your encrypted variant."